# Is there any way of getting the code that generates a component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to implement page to see examples of my components, see all the props and all that and then show something like this: [image: code block]

Right now I'm just copy pasting the code but that's not optimal. So how can I get the code that's needed to use a component?

Is there any way to achieve that without hard-coding it? Thanks.

Comment: Is this not your screenshot? This is called storybook, you can look it up, it provides exactly what you said, you can change props an see preview, or you can get all the code to copy and see the implementation in the "Docs" tab of the story. You only need to make a story file (jsx/tsx) and pass your component to it

Comment: Hi! Yes I know about Storybook but we don't really want to use it, bad experiences. Thank you anyway.

Comment: You can use the [rawloader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/raw-loader) (or its replacement for webpack v5) to get the source code of a component as a string and show it next to the rendered component.